# set Layout xml in android

Tags: layout

`

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`When I set the image on right side over transparent image(that is defined in relative layout) through layout_alignParentRight then image is placed at right of mobile screen  but if I give the actual size of the image then the secondry image is place at end of image but I don't want to hardcode width of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  should link the images of your layout for better understanding about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In First Imageview

```
SET android:layout_aliginparentleft="true"
```

I hope problem will be solve.